# Bad assembly reference in my .net project

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, gac

I'm reinstalling a server after it has crashed and I'm struggling with an old .net web-service. I'm not sure to have the latest version of source code (it doesn't compile on my computer in localhost) but I have the version ready to use on production environnement.

The problem is that application doesn't come with Microsoft.ReportViewer library inside its bin folder (I suppose it was referencing a library on GAC or something)... Anymway, after copied the 4 libraries I need into the bin folder, I have the following error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.*

How Could I change the assembly version without re-publishing my project from source code ? Can I ? I was thinking about web.config file... but I don't understand how to do it...

This is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Pour plus d’informations sur la configuration de votre application ASP.NET, rendez-vous sur 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="bdd" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=event_db;User Id=***;Trusted_connection=true; Application Name=WSFacture" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The assembly I want to use (the file I have copied in /bin/ folder) is 11.0.2802.16

Thanks a lot for helping me : code, source, tutorial... anything will help me :)

EDIT : Thanks, this is what i've done in my config file :

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.2802.16" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.40219.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.2802.16" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.2802.16" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

The error have evoluated... how can I see the dependancies ?

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.2802.16, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.*

EDIT 2 : Following the below comments, I've tried several syntaxe but no one is working... So I've made a different approach :
- I've downloaded the ViewReport (v10) package from NuGet into a .net solution > compile > get the generated .dll > copied them into my bin + remove the bindingRedirect sections from my config file ... and it's working !

Thanks a lot for your help ! It puts me in the right direction :)

Comment: You can try assembly binding redirect. Your config already has some. You need to add for `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` too. Check the version you have from file -> properties -> details -> file version and use that version as `newVersion`. Need to confirm that those versions have no breaking changes between them

Comment: Can you try it like this `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.2802.16" />`?

Comment: So you probably looked at the [AssemblyFileVersion] instead of the [AssemblyVersion].  Hard to see since it isn't displayed by Explorer, use ildasm.exe.